# How can I get elements from one component in another one by id or value?

Tags: reactjs, components

I've created a component to create follow and unfollow buttons and now I want to use this component in other components (like Suggestions).

In the suggestions component I want to show only the button that its value is equal to the user.id, but I am only able to get the 5 buttons from the original component.

Is there a way to select only the button that is equal to the user.id?

This is the component that creates the buttons:

```js
  render() {
    const { users, followingUsers } = this.state
    const userId = this.props.user[0].id
    return(
      <div>
        {users.map((user, index) => {
          if(userId !== user.id) {
            if(followingUsers.includes(user.user_name)) {
              return(
                <Button key={index} value={user.id} onClick={this.onUnfollow}>Unfollow</Button>
              )
            } else {
              return(
                <Button key={index} value={user.id} onClick={this.onFollow}>Follow</Button>
              )
            }
          } 
        })}
      </div>
      
    )
  }

}

export default withUser(Unfollowfollow);
```

Here is the suggestions component:

```js
  render() {
    const { users } = this.state
    const userId = this.props.user[0].id
    
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {users.map((user, index) => {
           if(user.id !== userId) {
             return (
              <Card className="users" key= {index}>
                <CardBody>
                  <CardImg className="picfollowers" top width="9%" src={user.image} />
                  <CardTitle onClick={() => this.handleClick(user.id)}>{user.user_name}</CardTitle>
                  <Unfollowfollow />
                    
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
             )}  
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default withUser(Suggestions);
```

[image]